# Avoid state mutation by Object.assign() inside map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In componentDidMount i did this:

```
     apps.forEach(app => {
            if (chosenAppId) {
                if (app.id === chosenAppId) {
                    this.setState({ map: this.props.map });
                }
            }
        });
```

and now when i do this in some function:

```
 this.setState({
            ...this.state.map,
            areas: this.state.map.areas.map(el =>
                el._id === area._id
                    ? Object.assign(el, {
                          chooseDevice: false,
                          editModal: true
                      })
                    : Object.assign(el, { chooseDevice: false })
            )
        });
```

I have persistent redux state, in this case I would expect that on reload this.state.map === this.props.map but somehow this object.assign mutated my redux state and on reload all is saved to reducer.

I narrowed it down that it has something to do with object.assign because if I .concat() something to this.state.map, that does not changes redux state.

How? I really do not get it. No redux action is dispatched, do not know how this can happen.

Comment: Your code may get [way more compact and safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60459622/11299053) completely without `Object.assign()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely right about the root cause of the issue - `Object.assign()` was mutating your original array items which you were referring to within `map()`.

To resolve this, simply get rid of `Object.assign()` mutating your state:

```
 this.setState({
    ...this.state.map,
    areas: this.state.map.areas.map(el => ({
       ...el,
       chooseDevice: false,
       ...(el._id === area.id && {editModal: true})
    }))
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

The line `Object.assign(el, { chooseDevice: false })` will mutate `el`.

It looks like you copied that from props (and thus likely the Redux store) into state.  So, it's the same object reference that was already inside the Redux store, and thus you're mutating the value that's in the store.

Note that [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) includes a mutation detection middleware by default that will throw errors when you accidentally mutate values.

Answer (score 1):

When you spread an object it doesn't *clone* existing properties, it simply copies them into the new object, meaning instance properties will remain e.g.

```js
    const obj = { numbers: [1, 2, 3], person: { name: 'Foo' } }
    const copy = { ...obj };
    copy.numbers.push(4);
    copy.person.name = 'Bar'
    console.log(obj.numbers) // [1,2,3,4]
    console.log(obj.person) // { name: 'Bar' }
    console.log(copy.numbers) // [1,2,3,4]
    console.log(copy.person) // { name: 'Bar' }
```

*Notice how the original object has been updated by changes made to the copy*

Therefore, when you spread your state into the local state i.e.

```
 ...this.state.map
```

And then use `Object.assign` on the instance properties, you are inadvertently updating the Redux state at the same time.

Comment: There's no point doing shallow copy of the state, OP may proceed with spread syntax perfectly fine, simply [avoiding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60459622/11299053) `Object.assign()` that bothers him

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I'm not sure what the point of your comment is here in relation to my answer? The OP asked _why_ this is happening, I've explained by way of example.

Comment: My apologies for that confusion.It seemed to me that you're suggesting some solution, it escaped my notice that it was just an explanation of *why* (like: - Doctor, I feel bad; - Yeah, that's because you're seek. Next!).

Answer (score 1):

### With Object.assign()

The `Object.assign()` method copies all enumerable own properties from one or more *source* objects to a *target* object.

`Object.assign(target, ...sources)`

**target**

The target object — what to apply the sources’ properties to, which is returned after it is modified.

**sources**

The source object(s) — objects containing the properties you want to apply.

[Object.assign() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

If you'd like it not to alter the element provided, target an empty object. That way `el` and the additional data in the third argument will be assigned to a new object, instead of overriding properties of `el`.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState.map,
    areas: prevState.map.areas.map(el =>
        el._id === area._id
            ? Object.assign({}, el, {
                  chooseDevice: false,
                  editModal: true
              })
            : Object.assign({}, el, { chooseDevice: false })
    )
}));
```

### With object spread (compact)

If you'd like to make ir more compact you can also turn it into an object spread, and use an inline if for the conditional change in `editModal`.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState.map,
    areas: prevState.map.areas.map(el => ({
        ...el,
        chooseDevice: false,
        editModal: el._id === area._id ? true : el.editModal
    }))
}));
```

**EDIT:** `this.state` should not be used in `setState`